# How keep the image rotated during the reverse movement?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm having a trouble with the effect I want to create. My body in the HTML file it's just a div with two images.

I was trying to give animation to the first image in the following way:

- in 0% it starts at the beginning of the div  (the fish's head is on the right)
- in 100% it ends in the end, but at this point I want to rotate the image and keep that effect until it gets 0% again. (that is, the fish should point towards the left during the reverse motion)

But it just rotates in 100% and no more. I don't know if this happens because I don't understand some concept of the animation property.

This is all my code:

```css
@keyframes fish01 {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  1% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    left: 90%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px double #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 1em 1em;
  background-image: url("https://i.onthe.io/vllkyt28101smv87bg.349283fe.jpg");
}
div img:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  animation-name: fish01;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
div img:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.hyperone.com.eg/media/catalog/product/cache/4/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/i/fish_1.png" />
    <img src="http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/fish_hero.png" />
  </div>
</section>
```

I've tried everything in the `@keyframes` and looked into [W3Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) about animation property, but it didn't help me. Any suggestions?

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/fs01a2qu/) is my attempt at the problem. It works a little better, but still isn't that good. I have tried adding `49%`/`50%` and it seems to be helping :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

The behavior that is seen is expected one based on your `@keyframes` and the `animation-direction` setting. When the animation's direction is set to alternate, the UA executes the animation from 0 to 100 for the odd numbered iterations, 100 to 0 for the even numbered iterations.

As per your keyframes, the `transform` goes from `rotateY(180deg)` to `rotateY(0deg)` at 1% of the animation's duration itself and so during the odd numbered iterations you don't see any visible rotation (as duration is  pretty small) and it goes from `rotateY(180deg)` (at 100%) to `rotateY(0deg)` (at 99%) because of which you don't get to see any visible rotation during even numbered iterations also.

The problem in writing keyframes for forward direction and re-using the same for the reverse (using `animation-direction`) is that it can be done only when the states are the same for both. In this case, it is not because the element should be in unrotated state during forward movement and should have `rotateY(180deg)` during the reverse movement.

**Solution:**

For the element to be seen in its rotated state, the `transform` must be retained for some time. So, for your case it is better to do away with the `animation-direction: alternate` setting and write both the forward and reverse motions within the keyframes itself like in the below snippet.

*(**Note:** Since we are writing both forward and reverse motions within the keyframes, you may have to double the `animation-duration`).*

```css
@keyframes fish01 {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  49.5% {
    left: 90%;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50.5% {
    left: 90%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px double #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 1em 1em;
  background-image: url("https://i.onthe.io/vllkyt28101smv87bg.349283fe.jpg");
}
div img:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  animation-name: fish01;
  animation-duration: 10s; /* double of original time */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
div img:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.hyperone.com.eg/media/catalog/product/cache/4/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/i/fish_1.png" />
    <img src="http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/fish_hero.png" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Harry, I could understand the concept of the animation-direction (I consider this the main problem I had), and the idea using the movement forward and re-using the same for the back. Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you had `animation-direction: alternate;` in your CSS. To compensate for removing this, you also need to make the `img` moving to `left: 90%` being at the `50%` mark in the animation, not the `100%` mark.

Hope this helps! :)

```css
@keyframes fish01{
        0% {
      left: 0%;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
     }
 
     49% {
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
     }
 
     50% {
         left: 90%;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
     }
 
     99% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
     }
        100% {
      left: 0%;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
     }
}

body {
 background-color: black;
}

div {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 18%;
 margin-top: 3%;
 width: 800px;
 height: 500px;
 border: 5px double #DDDDDD;
 border-radius: 1em 1em;
 background-image: url("https://i.onthe.io/vllkyt28101smv87bg.349283fe.jpg");
}

div img:nth-child(1) {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0px;
 top: 20%;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
 animation-name: fish01;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
} 

div img:nth-child(2) {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>CSS rotate animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Transicion02.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <section>
   <div>
    <img src="https://www.hyperone.com.eg/media/catalog/product/cache/4/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/i/fish_1.png"/>
    <img src="http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/fish_hero.png"/>
   </div>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same answers at same time (a drawback of not being able to see what you were about to do :D). By the way, that `100%` keyframe` is not needed at all because as soon as you reach `100%`, it will start executing the next iteration (which is `0%`).

Comment: Okay, I see... you answered it much better than me @Harry :). I spent ages working it out, and still am having trouble wrapping my head around it. It was the `animation-direction: alternate;` that I just missed. Anyway, okay, thanks! :D

Comment: @Harry Actually, on mine, the `100%` frame is needed. I just freezes for some reason. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs01a2qu/2/) with the `100%` frame taken out... odd...

Comment: What I meant is you could club both the 99% and 100% into one (that is, `left: 0%` should be part of it) and call it as 100%. Without that what happens is - the UA retains the element at `left: 90%` from 50 - 99% (which is half the duration). That is why you see it freezing for sometime.

Comment: I'm confused! :D Anyway, let's hope that one of us gets accepted :).

Comment: @Mirabilis, The fish is dying. Its going out of aquarium :P

Comment: Thanks @Mirabilis, a short explanation than Harry, but useful as well.

Comment: @CristinaPeónPadilla He deserved the acceptance... it's great just getting an upvote! :)